# Cannot download apps on Lumia 630

Tags: 8.1, store, parental-control, lumia-630

My Lumia 630 running Windows Phone 8.1 is trying to prevent me from downloading  any apps. I have signed into my Outlook account but nothing is working at all. I am told that if I want to download I have to ask a parent to go to windowsphone.com/family on their computer, sign in with their Microsoft account and set up My Family.

So help me out about that please?

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to read your English but it sounds like your [Microsoft Account](https://account.microsoft.com/account) - the primary account associated with your phone (and possibly also used to sign into your computer) - may be set up as a "child account" on a "[family group](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12413/microsoft-account-what-is-family-group)". If so, there may be restrictions on what apps you can download.

You need to either get the restrictions changed, get your account removed from the family group or marked as an "adult" member of the family, or hard-reset the phone (which will delete all data on the internal storage!) and sign in with a different account that is not a "child" account.